# Flex - how to switch to another SWC theme at run time?

Tags: apache-flex, themes

My goal is to have more themes for my application and if possible, bundle them with the application itself, *not* load them at runtime using `IStyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations()`.

Using the `theme` command-line option, you can have more than one "compile-time theme" bundled with your application according to [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html):

> **theme filename [...]** Specifies a list of theme files to use with this application. Theme files can be SWC files with CSS files inside them or CSS files.

However, I wasn't able to find an example how to actually do that (use the `+=` syntax on command line?) and switch between those themes at runtime. What API should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using the theme command-line option, you can have more than one
>   "compile-time theme" bundled with your application according to docs:

Yes, You can add additional themes using the += in your command line.

I do exactly this for the [Flextras mobile demos](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductSamples&ProductID=21); including both the generic Spark theme with the Mobile theme to create the app.

However, both themes will be attempted to be used.  I believe the second takes precedence.  That means for every class where you want to use the "other theme" you have to specify that theme be used manually.  This could get pretty complex very quickly; and you'll have to re-create a lot of spark skins in your application.  I've done some work for a client around this who wanted to use our mobile DropDownList in both their normal application and in a mobile application from the same code base.  I think the appropriate skin is conditionally applied at runtime using CSS; however we had to create a skin for the "non-mobile use" that explicitly specified the non-mobile skins for the individual elements (Such as the scroll bars)

Comment: So the answer is "no, you can't switch between, say, Spark and Halo or your custom theme SWC at runtime"?

Comment: @Borek You can't do it at runtime without writing a lot of code to make the switch.